# can't connect through socket /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am having trouble connecting to a database. Below is the Perl script that doesn't work:

```
use DBI;   

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    'dbi:mysql:orders;mysql_socket:/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
    $username,
    $password,
    { RaiseError => 0, AutoCommit => 0 },
)
  or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Normally when I try to open the `mysql.sock` file using open function there is a error but I can't open it.

Answer (score 6):

You should use '=' for extra parameters in dsn, so be it:

```
'dbi:mysql:orders;mysql_socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
```